# Check if last character is equal to - Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, trim

I'm currently using this formula which isn't working:

```
=IF(RIGHT(TRIM(L3),1)=4,1,0)
```

The value in L3 is 4, and so I would expect it to return a 1, not a 0, however I am getting the 0 returned from the if statement.

Could someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
=IF(RIGHT(TRIM(L3),1)="4",1,0)
```

Comment: @CallumDA  that's OK

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=IF(--RIGHT(TRIM(L3))=4,1,0)
```

`Right(..)` is returning a string, and being compared to a number. This will return `False` because `"4"` is not the same as `4`. The `--` converts the left hand side to a number as well so that `4=4`

Comment: This seems to work, thanks!

Also, enclosing the 4 in quotes worked as well..

Thanks again